# Sort Identities alphabetically+c#

Tags: c#, sorting, sid

I am working on the below code snippet where m_identities[memDesc].DisplayName a Windows SID DisplayName. The Display Name is in the LastName, FirstName format. I need help figuring out a couple of things,

1. Switch the  m_identities[memDesc].DisplayName format so that it is in the form of FirstName LastName
2. Sort the DisplayName by Alphabetical order when exporting it to CSV.

Any help is much appreciated!

```
static void Write(TeamFoundationIdentity group)
{
    string csv = string.Format("\n Members of group: {0} \n ", group.DisplayName);
    File.AppendAllText(@"C:\MembersLog\QueryMembers" + ".csv", csv);
    string csv1 = string.Format("==================================================\n");
    File.AppendAllText(@"C:\MembersLog\QueryMembers" + ".csv", csv1);

    foreach (IdentityDescriptor memDesc in group.Members)
    {
        string csv2 = string.Format(" {0} \n", m_identities[memDesc].DisplayName);
        File.AppendAllText(@"C:\MembersLog\QueryMembers" + ".csv", csv2);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: [according to documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.framework.server.teamfoundationidentity(v=vs.110).aspx), this can only be changed in the datasource and not in querying code: "The display name can come from the identity provider—like Active Directory or ACS—or may have been set as a custom display name within TFS". And "Lastname, Firstname" is a reasonable format for sorting, why would you want to reverse it? The sorting itself can be as easy as a LINQ `.OrderBy()` call.

Comment: Have you considered creating a custom class with these properties and populating a list of them from your group members?

Comment: @dlatikay: It is just a display preference requested by the User. I agree Lastname, Firstname is a reasonable format.